# How to resume an activity that is in background when tap on a Notification in Android

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification

In my app i have 3 different Activity. Main Activity, Album Activity and Camera Activity.
when my app is in background with:

1. Main activity, and user tap on notification, app resume with main activity.
2. Album activity, and user tap on notification, app resume with main activity.
3. Camera activity, and user tap on notification, app resume with main activity.

what i want is, if my app is in background with:

1. Main activity, and user tap on notification, app will resume with main activity.
2. Album activity, and user tap on notification, app will resume with album activity.
3. Camera activity, and user tap on notification, app will resume with camera activity.

how i can achieve this?? I am implementing FCM push notification and my project is Android with jetpack compose.

Thanks in advance.

```
   override fun onMessageReceived(message: RemoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(message)  

   val intent: Intent? = packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName)
            intent?.run {
                startActivity(this)
            }
    
            // it should be unique when push comes
            val requestCode = System.currentTimeMillis().toInt()
    
            // Pending intent for activity
            val pendingIntent: PendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, requestCode, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)

 
     notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_newarrivalicon)
                .setContentTitle(notification.title)
                .setContentText(notification.body)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setPriority(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
    
            with(NotificationManagerCompat.from(this)) {
                notify(requestCode, notificationBuilder.build())
            }
}
```

My Manifaest is like this

```
      <activity
        android:name=".ui.home.MainActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.CustomSplashScreenTheme"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        tools:ignore="LockedOrientationActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <data android:host="cognivision.jp" android:scheme="https" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.album.AlbumActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".ui.home.MainActivity"
        android:directBootAware="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_album"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.CustomSplashScreenTheme"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        tools:ignore="LockedOrientationActivity">
    </activity>
```

so, The onMessageRecived() triggered when the app running on foreground and i passed my package instead of specific activity to the intent. But when the app is on background, system handle the push notification and when i tap on notification my app start from Main activity always. But i don't want any specific activity to open, i want whatever the activity was on display before app going background to open exactly same activity and same screen.

Comment: Show us what you have tried and what exactly doesn't work the way you expect.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @AlexMamo Thanks for your comment. I have added my code. Sorry for inconvenient. I am new in writing here.

Comment: @Community. Thanks for your comment. I have added my code. Please have a look.